# How does one describe people who do not pick up irony, or vibes?

Tags: word-choice

I realise that at a severe level this can present as a symptom of Asperger's Syndrome, or High Functioning Autism. But I am not talking about that.

I am referring to people who just don't seem to understand irony. For example, let's say we have a doormat outside our house with the words 'BEWARE OF THE OLD WOMAN' written on it.

I think most people, at least in Britain, would see it as a joke. But some, at the extreme, might expect to meet a fierce old lady. Other's, less afflicted, might think it was a severe instance of political incorrectness. What do we call someone who just doesn't see the joke?

Or let's say that someone comes to dinner and is thoroughly miserable all evening, and the host or hostess just does not pick up on the fact that it is because of a difficulty that the guest has in their lives.

Do we say 'Penelope is 'insensitive'? No that isn't quite the word is it? Because had Penelope understood the reason she would have been as sympathetic as the next person. It was just that it simply never occurred to Penelope that her guest might be feeling sad about something, that she, the guest was not able to talk about. There are people who just don't pick up signs around them. Metaphorically they have no peripheral vision. They only see the obvious, and what is straight in front of them.

How do we describe such people?

Comment: Narrow-minded, maybe.: lacking in tolerance or breadth of vision.

Comment: My doormat says "You are here".

Comment: @Erik Kowal Define your terms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You're killing me! All right — 15% plus a £200 deposit. That's the best I can do for you.

Comment: In fact, I think I would actually understand it as your "at the extreme" example, by analogy to "BEWARE OF THE DOG", in that the houseowner is warning potential whippersnappers to keep out.

Comment: @Erik Kowal What's your doormat made of? 4500-year-old bristlecone pine bristles? Mind you, talking ones _are_ rare.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: "Dense", "tone deaf", "literalist".

Comment: It takes a bit of cognitive power to grasp irony: http://www.fastcodesign.com/3030622/evidence/why-youre-bad-at-understanding-irony

Comment: @Marthaª In what sense do you 'resemble the question'?

Comment: "imperceptive" comes to mind

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Why don't you post that as an answer? It is worthy of votes.

Comment: @WS2 I can't - the question is protected and I don't have 10 reputation earned on this site (reputation comes from other sites)

Comment: straightforward, may be

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overliteral) gives **overliteral** :

> overliteral ...
>
> *adjective*
>
> literal to a fault

where of course the sense of 'literal' used is that defined by Google Dictionary:

> literal  *adjective*
>
> 1. taking words in their usual or most basic sense without metaphor or exaggeration.

Comment: Spot on. You got it in one, Edwin. It is meaning 5d in the OED. I had forgotten that it could be used of a person. But I wouldn't bother to say 'overliteral', I would just say they were 'literal'. Thanks. *d. Of a person, the mind, etc.: apt to take words literally; characterized by an inability to recognize metaphor or understand humorous exaggeration, irony, or the like; lacking imagination; prosaic, literal-minded.* But thanks to others who have posted. Some interesting stuff there.

Comment: I'm delighted that doormats are now seen as authoritative sources. The spelling's usually better than that of Shakespeare.

Comment: We don't actually have such a doormat. My wife did draw the line when I was about to fork out for one at a street market. Literal? She probably has had to be to suffer me for 43 years!

Comment: I'm not keen on doormats with dirty comments.

Comment: I think we ought not to pursue this further!

Comment: I refuse to sweep it under the carpet.

Comment: I'm lost in a figurative maze. Where did I come in?

Comment: [related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8jm7BHxXSQ)

Answer (score 22):

For me the obvious choice would be [oblivious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oblivious) [TheFreeDictionary], but there are others: *unself-aware*, *immune to irony*, *obtuse*, etc.

Comment: Oblivious was my first thought as well.  Possibly clueless in some contexts.

Comment: +1 but I tend to see 'oblivion' as the manifestation of what I am describing rather than the thing itself. In short I think a 'literal' person is likely to be 'oblivious' to some things around them.

Comment: @WS2: I added "obtuse" to the list. Don't know if that works any better for you. But "oblivious" and "obtuse" have points of intersection, even if they're not perfect synonyms.

Answer (score 9):

This is really two questions together.

The person who fails to understand irony I would call **humour-challenged, humourless** or simply **[excessively] serious.**

The one who fails to pick up on other people's moods or mental states is **unobservant, oblivious, unaware** or **incognizant,** or possibly even **self-absorbed, literal-minded** or **tunnel-visioned.**

Comment: Yes, they're quite different. I can generally pick up irony quite well, but I sometimes have trouble with faces (I often don't recognize people when the light is behind them for example) and can miss subtle cues as a result. I understand emotion well enough, and am sensitive to mood conveyed by voice well enough, but unless I'm really studying someone's face, subtle facial cues can sometimes be hit and miss (making me seem oblivious to other people's moods in particular situations). Then again, if the light's in the wrong direction, I might not even know who it is until they speak/move.

Comment: @Glen_b - It's possible that you have a mild form of so-called 'face blindness' or [prosopagnosia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopagnosia)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know the term. I believe I may have it in a mild form.

Answer (score 4):

> **thick**
>
> 4. *informal*
>      of low intelligence; stupid.
>      "he's a bit thick"
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thick)

Comment: I would suggest that the use of such a word gets close to being an example of what I am talking about!

Comment: @WS2 \\ Golly, have I displeased or disappointed you?

Comment: Some people who are 'literal' are anything but 'thick'. Particularly when one gets into Aspergers and autism, you find exceedingly literal minds that can do advanced maths at a young age, or beat the computer at chess. Often 'literalness' is correlated with high functioning intelligence in narrow fields. A book I strongly recommend is *The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night time* by Mark Haddon.

Comment: _Thick_ and its cousin _dense_ would not be a general descriptor of such a person, but could be used in an informal, and perhaps jocular, manner, in light of some particular instance of this behavior. Its usage here would be similar to _oblivious_ if not intended in a mean-spirited way. (This is an Am.E. view of this slang.) Jocular put-downs to use in the moment are not what you're after, though, so I agree this doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: @AES And Americans aren't the only ones who say 'thick'.

Comment: If the definition is a quote (as it appears to be) please format it as such with `>` and cite its source in plain text. If it can be linked as well, so much the better. [Them's the rules.](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @Andrew Leach \\ I googled "thick." The very first result was obviously a dictionary entry which presented several of the various definitions of "thick." The dictionary was not named. I abstracted the pertinent definition. Since I do not normally begin my own sentences with "4.", I thought it obvious that the abstracted part came from a dictionary entry.

Comment: And you still haven't edited the answer to say where it came from. [Rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing): Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.

Comment: @Andrew Leach \\ And I just finished telling you that the dictionary was not named. Furthermore, I didn't copy the complete text of what Google provided -- just definition 4.

Answer (score 2):

By coincidence, my colleague coined this pun today: A person who doesn't "get" irony suffers from an *irony deficiency*.

Comment: Oh, that is genius of the first order! We need some way to get anaemia into the phrase somehow. (I shall leave that exercise to my betters!)

Answer (score -1):

> [serious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serious)

or

> [earnest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earnest)

or

> [sincere](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sincere)

These don't imply a lack of sense of humor, but rather the default state of taking things at face value.